# ZPL setup GX430t

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, cups, zpl-ii, pycups

I use Raspberry Pi connected to a Zebra GX430t with CUPS. I use the "Local Raw Printer" driver and I send the ZPL directly to the printer using Python.

I use the termal transfert mode, but I have a problem with the printer (300dpi), because the printing of the datamatrix is quite blurry, so I can't read it.

I emailed the Zebra support, and they told me to modify the temperature of the printing head, but I have no clue on how to do it with ZPL. I also have to modify the grayscale with ZPL. Do you know how to do one of this commands please ?

Plus, could you confirm that ^MTT is the command to set the printer to Thermal Transfert and that ^PW is used to set the width of the label ? Is the configuration saved in the printer, even when turned off, until the configuration change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `^MDa` command. where `a` is the value of the darkness level. Value is 0 to 30 in increments of 0.1.

Yes, `^MTa` sets printer mode where `a` is the setting, `T`= Thermal Transfer, `D`= Direct